# one of the things that I have noticed VS one of the things I have noticed

Tags: sentence-structure

Should it be:

> one of the things I have noticed

or:

> one of the things **that** I have noticed

I need to build right sentences and which one is correct form?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either one; neither is incorrect.

You might also use a contraction:

> one of the things that I've noticed

Some people recommend avoiding contractions in formal writing; however, unless you are writing, say, a contract or an academic paper, that rule would not apply.

Also, some might consider the 'that' to be a fluff word, so they would recommend leaving it out. The [Grammar Girl](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-to-delete-that) wrote a column explaining how you should leave it in when using "non-bridge verbs," which, according to her, "carry extra meaning beyond simply the idea of saying or thinking something, and [therefore] don’t sound as good when you omit the word 'that'."

Lastly, the structure you are using could be completely omitted in some contexts. While it's not grammatically incorrect, it's wordy, and sometimes writing can be improved if you simply say something more directly. For example:

> One of the things I've noticed is that it always rains when we schedule our company picnic.

This could be shortened to:

> I've noticed that it always rains when we schedule our company picnic.

Or even:

> It always rains when we schedule our company picnic.

So perhaps the bigger question isn't whether or not to include the word 'that' – it's whether you should include the phrase at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the things (that) I have observed.

You can use "that" in the sentence or drop it out; it makes no difference.

The "that" is a relative pronoun in the defining relative clause "that I have observed". As this relative pronoun is the object of the verb "observed" in the clause, it can be omitted, without any difference in the meaning. Another example:

It's one of the books that you gave me = It's one of the books you gave me.